# JQuery Mobile form submission causes Google Charts to disappear

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts and JQuery Mobile on one site.
In my file I have a form that sends some data, that is input through an autocomplete field.
When I submit that form, my chart disappears unexpectedly.

What would cause this behavior to happen?

Here is a link to my source code:
http://jsfiddle.net/5sea3dgq/1/

---

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>jQuery Mobile Example</h1>
        </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            <input name="test" type="text" id="example" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <script>
        var maxvals = 2, // anzahl aufzulistender elemente
            counter = 0; // nicht ändern
        var displayCount = 5; // anzahl anzuzeigender elemente
        var values = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
            ];
        function split( val ) {
            return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
            return split( term ).pop();
        }
        $("#example").bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }).keydown(function(event){
            var terms = split( this.value );
            console.info(maxvals, counter);
            // remove empty bit at the end
            terms.pop();
            if (terms.length < 2)
                $(this).autocomplete("enable");
            else
                $(this).autocomplete("disable");
            counter = terms.length;
        }).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response) {
                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    values, extractLast( request.term ) ).slice(0, displayCount) );
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                if (counter == maxvals)
                    return false;
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                // if one more item is allowed
                if (counter < maxvals - 1)
                    terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                counter++;
                if (counter == maxvals)
                    $(this).autocomplete("disable");
                return false;
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script>
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include the actual code in your question.

Comment: I updated the link. Does nobody understand my problem? Didn´t you look at my jsfiddle-file?

Comment: Does nobody want to help me? Is my problem explained bad, or what is wrong about my question?

Comment: Because your question is currently at -4, it won't be displayed in as many lists.  If you consider adding the code into your question as I suggested, it may encourage some to retract their downvotes, which will make your question more popular.

Comment: Just posted my code here. I hope you can explain me what i am doing wrong ;)

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem, but I don't know what test.php does.  What are you doing with the programming languages in the array on Post?

Comment: It´s just an example to show, that the form stops the google chart. The auto-complete field doesn´t really matter. I had it in my "real" page and also put it in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your code per se.

When working with JQuery Mobile (JQM), it changes a couple of things.  Chiefly among these, it changes the way form posts are handled.  Using JQM, by default all form posts are done via Ajax (you can observe this behavior in your network tab of your developer tools when you click submit or press enter).

**As taken from the JQM documentation:**

> In jQuery Mobile, form submissions are automatically handled using
>   Ajax whenever possible, creating a smooth transition between the form
>   and the result page. To ensure that your form submits are as intended,
>   be sure to specify action and method properties on your form element.
>   When unspecified, the method will default to get, and the action will
>   default to the current page's relative path (found via
>   $.mobile.path.get())
>
> Forms also accept attributes for transitions just like anchors, such
>   as data-transition="pop" and data-direction="reverse". To submit a
>   form without Ajax, you can either disable Ajax form handling globally,
>   or per form via the data-ajax="false" attribute. The target attribute
>   (as in target="_blank") is respected on forms as well, and will
>   default to the browser's handling of that target when the form
>   submits. Note that unlike anchors, the rel attribute is not allowed on
>   forms.

---

To solve your problem, you have a couple of options:

1. Use an Ajax function to post the form, so your graph never get's re-loaded.
2. Add the `data-ajax="false"` attribute and value to your form (which will cause a traditional form POST).

You can read more about this behavior at these sites:

- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html
- http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-correctly-submit-form-data-in-jquery-mobile/
- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0b3/docs/api/events.html
- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0b3/docs/api/globalconfig.html